# Configure Firebug to ignore JQuery POST

Tags: jquery, debugging, firebug

Is there away to configure Firebug so that it ignores (does not output) JQuery POSTs?

I am debugging with different levels of output (debug,error,warn,info,log) and if I do not filter I see to many POSTs.

[image]

I use the newest Firebug and Firefox versions

It would be a lot more comfortable to only see my console.logs (error,warn,etc).

Comment: Where do you actually see the POST requests?
They should be in the Net tab, not in the Console tab.

Comment: I do see them in both windows, Net and Console. Console points to line 8706 of the jquery-1.10.2.js which is `xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null );` I added a picture in my original post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to stop all ajax requests logging to the console you can try to click on Console tab dropdown arrow and uncheck `show XMLHTTPRequests` (this will stop logging of the GET requests too). I don't know if there is way to stop only the POST requests logging.

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly. Seems like I missed the little dropdown icon from the console. Now I can debug much more efficient. I do not need to debug GET and POST at the moment. If I need to I will switch it back on.

Comment: There is an issue fired for an RFC which will allow blackboxing of specific files, which will exclude them from the console and step by step debugging.
https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=4885